# Getting averages based on column values

Tags: mysql, pivot

Editing because I made a mistake transforming from my real example with lots of irrelevant details to the boxes example:

I have a table `BOXES` like this:

```
box_id  | color | dimension | value
1          blue     length      1       
1          blue     width       2      
2          blue     length      3      
2          blue     width       4      
3          red      length      5   
3          red      width       6      
4          red      length      7      
4          red      width       8     
5          green    length      9      
5          green    width       10 
6          green    length      11     
6          green    width       12
```

And I want to output average dimension for each color, like this:

```
color | avg_length | avg_width 
blue        2           3        
red         6           7         
green       10          11
```

Is there a SQL query to do so? I thought of doing 3 different queries like

```
WITH avg_len as (
  SELECT AVG(length) as l,color FROM `boxes`
), avg_width as (
  SELECT AVG(width) as w,color FROM `boxes`
), avg_height as (
  SELECT AVG(height) as h,color FROM `boxes`
```

but not sure how to tie them together. In my real data, there are thousands of "boxes" and a dozen or so "colors".

Comment: Shown query does not match shown sample data (non-existent column names in the query).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT color, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN dimension = 'length' THEN value END) avg_length, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN dimension = 'width' THEN value END) avg_width
FROM boxes
GROUP BY color;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f48d8b2fcaf3236a1c86be923f743748)

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler:

```
SELECT color, AVG(length), AVG(width), AVG(height)
    FROM boxes
    GROUP BY color;
```

After seeing the output, you may want to embellish it with `ROUND(...)` or some other formatting.

Another column with `COUNT(*) would say how many of each color.

**After making it more complex**

Step 1 is to "pivot".  This is to split the length and width into 2 columns instead of one.  (There are lots of examples of such, especially on stackoverflow.com with tag [pivot-table].)

```
SELECT color, AVG(length), AVG(width), AVG(height)
    FROM ( SELECT color,
                  IF (dimension = 'length', value, NULL) AS length,
                  IF (dimension = 'width',  value, NULL) AS width,
                  IF (dimension = 'height', value, NULL) AS height             
         ) AS pivot
    FROM boxes
    GROUP BY color;
```

But, that can be simplified to:

```
SELECT color,
       AVG(IF(dimension = 'length', value, NULL)) AS length,
       AVG(IF(dimension = 'width',  value, NULL)) AS width,
       AVG(IF(dimension = 'height', value, NULL)) AS height          
    FROM boxes
    GROUP BY color;
```

Note:  `NULLs` are ignored in many aggregates, including `AVG`.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I was asking the wrong problem when transforming from my real world database to the toy boxes example, so I edited to update. If that is poor form I could undo the edit, accept your answer, and ask a new question